# subdivision problem

Tags: mesh, geometry, artifacts

I started learning blender a month ago, I'm trying to make a jukebox but I got some problems
This is what I've done so far:
[image: no subdivision]

When I add subdivion:[image: with subdivision]

Adding holding loops(?) helps but creates artifacts and a "nipple": [image: holding loops]

How can I fix that? obs: I used knife project and extrude to create the speaker, maybe thats the problem.

Comment: Ngons and subsurf are always problematic, avoid creating geometry using boolean or knife project. To mix hard and soft edges use creases and supporting loops

Comment: Read the following related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105386/weird-problem-with-faces-black-lines/105390#105390. Instead of cutting holes with knife project or booleann operations, and creating problematic topology by that approach, use a modeling workflow that allows you to be in control of the resulting topology. If you are learning how to use blender don't take the shortcut approach. Proper modeling and proper topology will save you headaches down the road,