# how to correct topology after boolean operation?

Tags: mesh, topology

So I have used the boolean operation to create a spherical hole inside a cube and was wondering how I could correct the topology. The result of this was: [image: edit mode of sphere]

So I was wondering how I can edit the topology so I can use subsurface modifier or if it is better if I Use a different method to create the hole. If I should recreate it a different way than what would be a good way keeping in mind that this is from a cube.

Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/cutting-a-circular-hole-in-a-hollow-cylinder-without-distorting-the-cylinder https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30996/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-hole-into-an-object https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118586/extruding-a-circular-shape-from-a-non-circular-object

Comment: The best way to have correct topology is to **avoid booleans**. Don't create problems that you have to spend time fixing later. Read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105386/weird-problem-with-faces-black-lines and [8 ways to make holes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA)

Comment: a quick way to fix your geometry is to create a bevel all along the edges so that when you give your object a Subdivision Surface it won't mess the whole shape.

Answer (score 0):

First triangulate the model.

After that, add a subdivison modifier, with simple and one with Catmull-Clark selected. Then do loopcuts, where you want to have sharp edges. Slide the loopcuts till the edges, but not on them, just a little bit before.
You have to play a little bit with the strengt of the modfiere.